# Xcode 4.5 -iOS- Read email/update text field inside app

Tags: xcode, email

Is it possible to read the content of lets say the last email in a specific email inbox? I´m developing an app for a company and I would like for anyone to be able to send an email to a specific address, and then the content of that email would be visible in a text field inside the app. But for that to work the app will have to be able to have access to a specific email. I bet there are other ways of updating a textfield inside an app but this would make it so easy for everyone to be able to update this news feed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Third-party apps have no access to the system Mail app’s database. If you want to access the contents of an email, you’ll need to connect to that server and retrieve its mail yourself.